# not able to get icons when we search for any weather location using retrofit

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio

***below is the main code on button click i am getting temperature and humidity but on add  those two line of getting summary and icon, app is crashing                                                                                                                                                                                                        ***

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editText;
     private Button button;
    private TextView responseText;
    ImageView iconImageView;
    TextView summaryTextView;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();}    
 private void init() {
    editText = findViewById(R.id.city_name);
    button = findViewById(R.id.city_click);
    responseText = findViewById(R.id.response_text);
    iconImageView = findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
    summaryTextView = findViewById(R.id.summaryTextView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fetchWeatherDetails();
            }
        });
    }
    private void fetchWeatherDetails() {
        Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient();
        weatherapis weatherAPIs = retrofit.create(weatherapis.class);
        Call<Weather> call;
        call = weatherAPIs.getWeatherByCity((editText.getText().toString()),"c70504e5e7ee0c5962f9407a45a2e75b");
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    Weather wResponse = (Weather) response.body();
                    responseText.setText("Temp: " + wResponse.getMain().getTemp() + "\n " +
                            "Humidity: " + wResponse.getMain().getHumidity() + "\n" +
                            //  "icon:"+ wResponse.getWeather_().getIcon() +"\n"+
                            "Pressure: " + wResponse.getMain().getPressure());
                   summaryTextView.setText(wResponse.getCurrently().getSummary());
                   iconImageView.setImageResource(WeatherIconUtil.ICONS.get(wResponse.getCurrently().getIcon()));
                }}
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {}});
    }
```

***below is Weathericonutil class to get icons***

```
public final class WeatherIconUtil {
public static final Map<String, Integer> ICONS;
static {
    Map<String, Integer> iconMap = new HashMap<>();
    iconMap.put("clear-day", R.drawable.ic_clear_day);
    iconMap.put("clear-night", R.drawable.ic_clear_night);
    iconMap.put("rain", R.drawable.ic_rain);
    iconMap.put("snow", R.drawable.ic_snow);
    iconMap.put("sleet", R.drawable.ic_sleet);
    iconMap.put("wind", R.drawable.ic_wind);
    iconMap.put("fog", R.drawable.ic_fog);
    iconMap.put("cloudy", R.drawable.ic_cloudy);
    iconMap.put("partly-cloudy-day", R.drawable.ic_partly_cloudy_day);
    iconMap.put("partly-cloudy-night", R.drawable.ic_partly_cloudy_night);
    iconMap.put("thunderstorm", R.drawable.ic_thunderstorm);

    ICONS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(iconMap);
}
}
```

***below is my weather api interface***

```
public interface weatherapis {
String api_key = "my key";
String BASE_URL= "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";
// static Retrofit retrofit = null;
@GET("/data/2.5/weather")
Call<Weather> getCurrently();

/*
    Get request to fetch city weather.Takes in two parameter-city name and API key.
    */
    @GET("/data/2.5/weather")
    Call<Weather> getWeatherByCity(@Query("q") String city, @Query("appid") String apiKey);

}
```

*** currently class from models***

```
public class Currently {

@SerializedName("time")
@Expose
private Integer time;
@SerializedName("summary")
@Expose
private String summary;
@SerializedName("icon")
@Expose
private String icon;
@SerializedName("temperature")
@Expose
private Double temperature;

public Integer getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(Integer time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getSummary() {
    return summary;
}

public void setSummary(String summary) {
    this.summary = summary;
}

public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

public Double getTemperature() {
    return temperature;
}

public void setTemperature(Double temperature) {
    this.temperature = temperature;
}

}
```

***below network client***

```
public class NetworkClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org";
public static Retrofit retrofit;
/*
This public static method will return Retrofit client
anywhere in the appplication
*/

public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient() {
    //If condition to ensure we don't create multiple retrofit instances in a single application
    if (retrofit == null) {
        //Defining the Retrofit using Builder
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL) //This is the only mandatory call on Builder object.
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) // Convertor library used to convert response into POJO
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}

}
```

***crash log on geting suumary and icon in mainactivity ***

```
09-12 15:54:18.648 12336-12336/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-12 15:54:18.648 12336-12336/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nv.thisisitman, PID: 12336
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String models.Currently.getSummary()' on a null object reference
    at com.nv.thisisitman.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:63)
    at retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallback$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:86)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6239)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZyoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Comment: *`app is crashing`* Where is your Crash log?

Comment: ***crash on ***     summaryTextView.setText(wResponse.getCurrently().getSummary());
                   iconImageView.setImageResource(WeatherIconUtil.ICONS.get(wResponse.getCurrently().getIcon()));

Comment: crash log added

Comment: Your `wResponse.getCurrently().getSummary()` retuning  `null`

Comment: means?                              what should i do?